# Default text in a specific post type, but not visible?

Tags: custom-post-types, customization

I want to do two things. For a specific post type I want to have a default text. This have I been able to do with this code:

```
add_filter( 'default_content', 'my_editor_content', 10, 2 );

function my_editor_content( $content, $post ) {

    switch( $post->post_type ) {
        case 'posttypehere':
            $content = 'mydefaultposttextgoeshere';
    }

    return $content;
}
```

This works great, I can see the text and it gets saved to the database.
But now I want to disable the text box entirely from this specific post type.
Which I can do with this code:

```
add_action('init', 'init_remove_support',100);
function init_remove_support(){
    $post_type = 'posttypehere';
    remove_post_type_support( $post_type, 'editor');
}
```

And this will disable the text box.

But now the problem is that the default text will not be saved to the post when I publish it. So how can I achieve both?

Thank you!

Comment: You could save the text in the theme - "single-posttypehere.php" would display it wherever you want, automatically, without you having to save it into the database. However, then it would not appear in RSS feeds etc. To save it in the post content, hook to `save_post` so every time the post is saved, your hard-coded content gets saved as the content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can manually hook into the [`save_post`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/save_post) action and update the post's content on save. Here's a simple piece of code that does it:

```
add_action( 'save_post', 'update_post_content' );
function update_post_content($post_id) {

    // If this is a revision, get real post ID
    if ( $parent_id = wp_is_post_revision( $post_id ) ) {
        $post_id = $parent_id;
    }

    // Get the current post type
    $post_type = get_post_type($post_id);

    // Check if it's a custom post type
    if ( 'posttypehere' != $post_type ) return;

    // unhook this function so it doesn't loop infinitely
    remove_action( 'save_post', 'update_post_content' );

    // update the post, which calls save_post again
    wp_update_post( 
        array( 
            'ID'            => $post_id, 
            'post_content'  => 'content here' 
        ) 
    );

    // re-hook this function
    add_action( 'save_post', 'update_post_content' );
}
```

Comment: This solved my problem! I can use this together with the code to hide the text area. And it still saves! Thank you very much!